# Provide values to a stored procedure in mySql using java program

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Im new to databases so please pardon me if my question sounds stupid.

I have this mysql procedure -

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO table1 
  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?);
COMMIT;
```

The '?' here represents the values that will be available in my java program. I want to insert those values from my java program into this procedure and run it.
Please note that the actual procedure is quite long so I cannot use `Prepared Statement`

How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that I cannot use PreparedStatement. This procedure is actually a transaction with many insert statements. Can this be achieved using functions?

Comment: For stored procedure use `CallableStatement`.

Comment: You need to create a stored procedure with IN,OUT parameters and then use CallableStatement to execute it. It has setter methods to set parameter values and registerOutParameter and getters for retrieving out parameters. You'll get lot of tutorials on a simple search. Eg http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html